# PHP testing for a next item

Tags: php, loops, key

I can't figure out how to test if there's a next item in my array by using the key to test against.  I think this is better explained in code. I know there's an easier way, I'm just a noob!

Basically I want to know if there is another item in the array and if so get the ->comp_id value.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($allcomps); $i++)
    {
        if($allcomps[$i]->comp_id  == $curCompID)
        {
            $currentIndex = $i;
            if($allcomps[$i+1]->comp_id == null )
            {
                echo "there isn't a next";
            }
            //echo $allcomps[$currentIndex+1]->comp_id;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `if (isset($allcomps[$i + 1])) { echo $allcomps[$i + 1]->comp_id; }`

Comment: @scrowler, I think the OP would want `(!isset($allcomps[$i + 1]))`

Comment: @Devon why? *I want to know if there is another item in the array, and if so get the `comp_id` value*

Comment: Well, actually it's a bit confusing.  The code says one thing but the question says and if so get the ->comp_id value.  So I guess the OP will have to decide on one.

Answer (score 0):

You're already looping through allcomps, so why do you need a check for the next one?

Why not check within the loop?

```
for($i=0; $i<count($allcomps); $i++) {
  if (isset($allcomps[$i]->comp_id) and $allcomps[$i]->comp_id == $curCompID) {
    $currentIndex = $i;
  }
}
```

I think a foreach might be even easier:

```
foreach($allcomps as $i=>$comp) {
  if (isset($comp->comp_id) and $comp->comp_id == $curCompID) {
    $currentIndex = $i;
  }
}
```